# Dispersion copula

Tags: copula, dispersion

Linear correlation controls two aspects : that of **level** (Basket options) and that of **dispersion** (spread options). Is there a copula that has two separate parameters for each?

Comment: It were helpful to elaborate a bit and to phrase your question in fully defined terms.

Comment: @gg a product whose payoff is $S_1 + S_2$ has a positive sensitivity to the correlation unlike a spread option whose payoff is $S_2 - S_1$. Correlation being also a proxy of dispersion. As a matter of fact those two effects are different (we could never find one correlation that would calibrate to market quotations of both products). Hence my question.